# c++ boost program options always giving default value

Tags: c++, boost-program-options

I'm struggling to get boost program options to work properly. I need to be able to start my program from the terminal window (Linux) with an optional argument that takes a value. No matter what I did, this would not work; no matter what value I typed from the terminal, it just returned the default value. Furthermore, if I did not include the option in my termina command, it returned with

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of      'boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injec    tor<std::logic_error> >'                                                                                                                                                   
 what():  character conversion   failed                                                                                                              
Aborted (core dumped)
```

So I found a minimal example on the internet to see if it was something I had done wrong. Here is the example I found that does a similar thing that I need:

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <boost/program_options.hpp>

namespace po = boost::program_options;

int main  (int argc, char* argv[]) {

po::options_description desc("Usage");
desc.add_options()
  ("robots", po::value<int>()->default_value(3), 
 "How many robots do you want to send on a murderous rampage?");

po::variables_map opts;
po::store(po::parse_command_line(argc, argv, desc), opts);

try {
   po::notify(opts);
} 
catch (std::exception& e) {
   std::cerr << "Error: " << e.what() << "\n";
   return 1;
}

int nRobots = opts["robots"].as<int>(); 
// automatically assigns default when option not supplied by user!!

std::cout << nRobots << " robots have begun the silicon revolution" 
    << std::endl;
 return 0;
}
```

This does exactly the same thing however, and I am starting to think this is either a bug in Boost (unlikely I guess) or something about my system that it doesn't like?

Could anybody hint at what might be wrong please? Thanks

Comment: This works correctly for me. Please make sure that your reproducible examples actually *reproduce* the error in question.

Comment: Your code [works here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8b1c8b420b7e58a2).

Comment: @nrussell

As I said in my post, that code does reproduce the error on my machine, and suspected it was a bug either with my version of Boost (v1.60) or something on my system. At least now I know the code does work, thank you.

Comment: Which version of Boost are you using, and what command are you compiling your program with?

Comment: @nrussell

Using v1.60. It compiles fine, but the command I'm compiling with is:
    g++ popt_test.cpp -lboost_program_options

Comment: @nrussell

I have just removed and reinstalled boost and it seems to now be working fine: both my test example and my own program.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the exact same problem transitioning from `1.58` to `1.61`.
My problem was that I was linking `1.61` boost header code with old `1.58` shared libraries.

You may have installed a newer version of boost, but that doesn't mean you still aren't linking with old boost libraries.  Check your linker.  Check your system files.
A good check you can do on your program, is to run it through `gdb`, have it crash, and look at the backtrace (bt).  It will show the boost version numbers in the backtrace.  See if it matches what you expected.

If relevant, I was on Ubuntu and built from source:

```
sudo ./bootstrap.sh --prefix=/usr
sudo ./b2 install threading=multi link=shared
```

This resulted in my library files being located at `/usr/lib/libboost*`.
However, my linker was looking in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost*`.

A simple `cp -Pf` over the old files solved my problem.